# How to divide the screen into four parts with scalable items using Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a layout that will contain 4 buttons with some margin, ideally it would automatically scale the buttons when the size of the screen changes like so:

[image: Example of what I want] [image: Other example of what I want]

This is my code so far:

```
  GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  childAspectRatio: 1.25,
  children: [
    ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow),
        child: const Text('Switch camera')),
    ElevatedButton(
        style:
            ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        child: const Text('Change video quality')),
    ElevatedButton(
        style:
            ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.green),
        child: const Text('Take a picture')),
    ElevatedButton(
        style:
            ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
        child: const Text('End call')),
  ],
),
```

Which results in the following view:

[image: Current result]

I want all buttons to automatically expand filling all available space, how can I achieve this using Flutter?

Comment: Looks like a GridView to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var padding = 15.0;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: padding,top: padding,right: padding),
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: padding,right: padding),
                    color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: padding,top: padding,bottom: padding,right: padding),
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: padding,right: padding,bottom: padding),
                    color: Colors.cyan,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Pic]

Comment: to complex...  just use Column( children:[ Expanded(Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.evently)) ,Expanded(child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.evently)) ] )  @IvanHid

Comment: yeah, you're right. Fixed it with your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! With this I just needed to add minimumSize: const Size(
                                    double.infinity, double.infinity), to the style of my button and it works perfectly!